# Implement ad hoc command inside packaged Spring netty jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We want to add a command to our existing Spring boot WebFlux application so that we can issue a command with the packaged jar to perform some cleanup (query database, issue some API calls). While sharing logic with the actual server code, the command itself is fully autonomous and doesn't have to be run on the same server or doesn't even need a running server. Also the cleanup command is designed to be crash-only and we are using a NoSQL database so those APIs from spring-batch which requires an implementation of jobRepository seems to be unnecessary and not easy to setup.

I am trying to do the following:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringReactiveApplication {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    if (Arrays.asList(args).contains("runJob")) {
      var context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringReactiveApplication.class);
      var component = context.getBean(MyComponent.class);
      component.runJob().block();
    } else {
      SpringApplication.run(SpringReactiveApplication.class);
    }
  }
}
```

But when I tried to run this on my local computer `java -jar app.jar runJob`, it seems the context was picking up a wrong `application-xxxx.properties` even if I have environment variable set `spring_profiles_active=local`. However, if I just run `java -jar app.jar` the server was able to start successfully with local profile set.

**EDIT**

I actually got it working with something like below:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringReactiveApplication {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    if (Arrays.asList(args).contains("runJob")) {
      var app = new SpringApplication(SpringReactiveApplication.class);
      app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
      var context = app.run(args);
      var component = context.getBean(MyComponent.class);
      component.runJob().block();
    } else {
      SpringApplication.run(SpringReactiveApplication.class);
    }
  }
}
```

But the question remains since I feel my solution is more of a hack.

Also giving a bit context here - the reason we want to add this into our spring-boot jar is that we want to use the same container image in our k8s which can be used as a web deployment as well as a background job.

Comment: If you are using an environment variable to set the active profile it should be SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.properties-and-configuration.set-active-spring-profiles

Comment: I think both should work. Also it works and can find the correct properties file when I run the jar as web service. Anyway, I got it working now - see my edit if you are interested but it's more like a hack.